# Gradle Plugin ‘java-library’ not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, plugins

I'm having an issue as of late when compiling a java library with Gradle 4.0.1 (this issue was happening with 3.5 as well) on Windows with IntelliJ using the 'java-library' plugin. Here is a snipped of my build script:

```
buildscript{
    repositories{
        jcenter();
    }
    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.5'
        classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+'
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.15.0'
    }
}

configurations{
    taglibs{ transitive = false}
    enhance
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
```

and here is what happens when I try to build:

> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 0.115 secs
>
> Plugin with id 'java-library' not found.

This was working fine until recently.

Comment: your script works for me pretty well

Comment: What command are you using to invoke Gradle? Are you using the Gradle wrapper? What does Gradle output when you execute `./gradlew --version`?

Comment: I'm not using the gradle wrapper, I'm using the local gradle distribution (4.0.1)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you switched to Gradle 4.0.1 in the Intellij IDEA preferences.

`java-library` plugin was not available for Gradle 3.5

Comment: What if you can't update:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':…'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
   > Gradle version 2.10 is required. 
```